# how to save high quality image of graph plot in pyqtgraph like using Dpi?

Tags: python, plot, graph, dpi, pyqtgraph

I am plotting graph 2D plot in pyqtgraph, and when I am exporting the plot as an image it is saving a low-quality image. so is there any option in pyqtgraph to save high-quality image of the plot like by changing the **DPI** value.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import numpy as np
   
x= [10,15,20,25,30,35]
y= [11.142,9.6651,9.4700,9.7334,9.0865,9.1769]
x1= [10,15,20,25,30,35]
y1= [11.1032,9.6214,8.8619,9.0126,8.2405,8.4704]

plt = pg.plot()
plt.showGrid(x=True,y=True)
plt.addLegend()
plt.setBackground('w')

styles = {"color": "#000000", "font-size": "20px"}
plt.setLabel('left', 'Y axis', **styles)
plt.setLabel('bottom', 'X axis',**styles)
plt.setTitle("Graph",fontweight='bold',color='k', size="20pt")
plt.setXRange(10,40)
plt.setYRange(5,25)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph plot')


c1 = plt.plot(x, y, pen='b', symbol='o', symbolPen='b', symbolBrush=('b'), name="blue")
c2 = plt.plot(x1, y1, pen='r', symbol='t', symbolPen='r', symbolBrush=('r'), name="red")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(pg.QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

I am exporting the plot by right-clicking on the plot and then clicking on export option.
[image]

Comment: [krishna kakade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8926157) wrote and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086557) saying "check this link for the detailed solution https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact set of image formats supported will depend on your Qt libraries but for getting more detailed solution how to export images in a good format without affecting a height/pixels parameter check this link for a detailed explanation https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52389032.html